# Quick setting up gravitational teleport jump box (bastion host)

Tags: linux

I'm trying to setup a cluster in my virtual box according to the quickstart docs here https://gravitational.com/teleport/docs/quickstart/

I've got a problem with adding a new node to the cluster. When I run on the new node the command (gotten from auth server):
`sudo teleport start --roles=node --token=TOKEN --auth-server=192.168.99.101:3025`, I get the error message:

`ERRO [PROC:1]    Critical service ssh.node has exited with error Get https://teleport.cluster.local/v2/namespaces/default: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, aborting. service/signals.go:148`

EDIT: I tried as well the approach described in the docs https://gravitational.com/teleport/docs/admin-guide/#adding-nodes-to-the-cluster . There was the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From https://gravitational.com/teleport/docs/admin-guide/#adding-nodes-to-the-cluster paragraph "Untrusted auth servers":

> In a zero-trust environment, you must assume that an attacker can highjack the IP address of the auth server e.g. 10.0.10.5. To prevent this from happening, you need to distribute the CA certificate of the auth server to the node prior to adding it:

```
# on the auth server:
$ tctl auth export --type=tls > ca.cert

# on the new node, prior to calling 'teleport start'
$ mkdir -p /var/lib/teleport
$ cp ca.cert /var/lib/teleport/ca.cert
```

The message suggests you perhaps didn't do this yet?

Comment: I did with the same error.